# react js - passing a value from child to parent, then to another child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit: 
Thanks for the responses guys. I've found the root of my problem here. For some reason the code (I've inherited from others) is calling up my component multiple times, overwriting my values. I think I can take it from here. Thanks anyway guys.

My components are set up like this:

```
A
- B
- C
```

And I would like B, when triggered, to pass a value back to A and set a new state. Then, when an event is triggered, A would pass that value to C as a prop.

So far, I've tried creating a function in A then pass it to B as a prop, as such:

```
A: 

handler(){
    setState({value: someVal});
}

render(){
    <B func={this.handler}/>
    eventTriggered <C cProp={this.state.value}/>
}
```

However, as (I've found out that) setState() is asynchronous, when it is time for C to mount, this.state.value might not have the value from B assigned yet.

Perhaps my entire approach is wrong, but is there anyway of remedying this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your code that simulates this case with any online editor? Will be easier to get your context that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `render()` method, you could not render C until the event has been triggered and state has a value e.g.

```
render() {
    return (
        <B func={this.handler} />
        {eventTriggered && this.state.value &&
            <C cProp={this.state.value} />
        }
    )
}
```

EDIT:

Make sure in component A you have:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've also tried this method, but then C just never gets mounted because this.state.value never seemed change.

Comment: @qunayu are you binding `handler` to your parent component `this`?

Answer (score 0):

typically, you can solve this kind of issue by using a second argument to `setState` (a function)

eg

```
handleClick(e){
  this.setState({value: e.target.value}, () => this.props.onChange(this.state.value))
}
```

the second function will only fire the onChange prop when the state is reconciled. If you want to fire it earlier, send the raw value of `e.target.value` instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried using a callback function, but because the action I'm trying to accomplish is sending the values ultimately as a props to another component in render(),  I'm not sure if callbacks are the way to go in my case.